# How to make a floating range bar graph python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to make a graph that shows pre test and post test results for various sports skills. I can not figure out how I would make a graph similar to the image which is what the graph should look like any help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FEWa.jpg

Comment: It would be a bit easier to answer if you mentioned your data source and or what tools you were using

Comment: hey jeffrey I am mainly using matplotlib and my data source is a set of 10 numbers for each bar. I dont have the exact numbers used in that example but that is how the data is. thanks